# Filtering duplicated rows conditionally

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

What would be a good tidyverse approach to this type of problem? I want to filter out the duplicated rows of `group` that have an `NA` in them (keeping the row that has values for both `var1` and `var2`) but *keep* the rows when there is no duplicated value in `group`. `dat` illustrates the raw example with `expected_output` showing what I'd hope to have.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tibble)

dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~var1, ~var2,
  "A", "foo", NA,
  "A", "foo", "bar",
  "B", "foo", NA,
  "C", NA, "bar",
  "C", "foo", "bar",
  "D", NA, "bar",
  "E", "foo", "bar",
  "E", NA, "bar"
)



expected_output <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~var1, ~var2,
  "A", "foo", "bar",
  "B", "foo", NA,
  "C", "foo", "bar",
  "D", NA, "bar",
  "E", "foo", "bar"
)
expected_output
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   group var1  var2 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 A     foo   bar  
#> 2 B     foo   <NA> 
#> 3 C     foo   bar  
#> 4 D     <NA>  bar  
#> 5 E     foo   bar
```

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 - if the duplicate rows are located in different positions for each group (e.g. first, last or somewhere in between)**

```
dat %>%
  arrange(group,var1,var2) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice_head() %>% 
  ungroup()
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  group var1  var2 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     foo   bar  
2 B     foo   NA   
3 C     foo   bar  
4 D     NA    bar  
5 E     foo   bar
```

---

**Solution 2 - if the duplicate row is always the last row of that group**

You can use `duplicated` with the `fromLast` option set to keep the last matched line, find the index of matches, negate it, and use that to remove duplicates as follows:

```
dat[!duplicated(dat$group, fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

which gives your requested output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  group var1  var2 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     foo   bar  
2 B     foo   NA   
3 C     foo   bar  
4 D     NA    bar
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this isn't actually the requested output.

Comment: Hi @boshek, thanks for pointing that out.  I updated the answer to keep last match instead of the first for duplicated lines.

Comment: Or a similar option with `dplyr` `dat %>% filter(!duplicated(group, fromLast = TRUE))`

Comment: I hate to quibble but this feels pretty fragile since it relies on row order doesn't it?

Comment: Hi @boshek, yes definitely depends on row order, if you data isn't laid out with the last duplicate row always being the one you want to keep then this solution won't work. Can you provide an updated ```dat``` dataframe example with some additional lines you want to extract that are not the last row as in the pattern above?

Comment: Hi @boshek, posted an additional solution above based on your updated dataset.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
dat %>% 
 group_by(group) %>%
 slice_max(rowSums(!is.na(across(c(var1, var2)))), 1)

  group var1  var2 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     foo   bar  
2 B     foo   <NA> 
3 C     foo   bar  
4 D     <NA>  bar
```